# How to pass multiple model objects from controller and how to pass all as command objects into the form:form in spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

The scenario is like I want to pass more than one model objects from controller which I can achieve like,

```
 model .addAttribute(“person”, new Person());
 model.addAttribute(“address”, new Address());
```

But how to pass both of them or more in spring view

```
<form:form action=”registration” command=”person”>
```

As it only allows me to pass only one command . Then how to pass all the require command over their.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add both `person` and `address` into an enveloping object called `personDetails` and pass that to the form.

```
class PersonDetails {
    private Person person;
    private Address address;

    ...
}


PersonDetails personDetails = new PersonDetails();
personDetails.setPerson(new Person());
personDetails.setAddress(new Address());

model.addAttribute(“personDetails”, personDetails);


<form:form action=”registration” command=”personDetails”>
```

Once you do that, you'll have to modify the `path`s appropriately.

```
<form:input path="firstName" />
```

becomes

```
<form:input path="person.firstName" />
```

Other more elegant option is to enclose `Address` within the `Person` and just expose the `Person` as a command. Just as @Seabook mentioned in his answer below.

Comment: Hi, Really appreciate your quick answer and its working.  Still I want to know, is there any way that spring gives us a way to pass more than one command objects in <form:form>?

Comment: No. This is against the command pattern! Note that when you add attributes to model using `model.addAttribute`, you have all those variables available to you in the JSP. You can simply use EL to access them.

Comment: @adarshr I'd like to know if my 2nd entity has a List<object> which is part of the 1st entity, how do I pass the 2nd entity object to the form ?