# Passing both HashMap and ArrayList values to view file

Tags: java, arrays, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC and I am trying to pass both HashMap and ArrayList values to my view file. But I can't find a way to achive this.

Could you please help me?

My Controller Mehtod

```
@RequestMapping(value="/do_register", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView RegistrationForm(@ModelAttribute Subscriber subscriber, BindingResult result)
{

  HashMap<Integer, String> interest = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    interest.put(1,"Java");
    interest.put(2,"PHP");
    interest.put(3, "Both");

  List<City> myCities = subService.getCity();

 // I want to pass both "myCities" and "interest" to my view File
 return new ModelAndView("regForm", "records", " ");

}
```

Form

```
<c:url var="action" value="/register" ></c:url>
<form:form action="${action}" modelAttribute="subscriber" method="POST" >

    <div>
    <label>City</label>
    <form:select path="city">
    <c:forEach items="${records}" var="city">
            <option value="${city.cityId}">${city.cityName}</option>            
    </c:forEach>
    </form:select>
    </div>

    <div>
    <label>Interests</label>
    <form:checkboxes path="interest" items="${records.interests}"/>     
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `ModelAndView` contains a `Model` which is a kind of `Map`. It can contain as many objects as you need. Simply modify your code like :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/do_register", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView RegistrationForm(@ModelAttribute Subscriber subscriber, BindingResult result)
{

    ...
    // I want to pass both "myCities" and "interest" to my view File
    ModelAndView mav =  ModelAndView("regForm");
    mav.addAttribute("interests", interest);
    mav.addAttribute("records", myCities);
    return mav;
}
```

And you find your objects in the JSP with `${records}` and `${interests}`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about surrounding logic in your code base but one way to do that is create Envelop object contain both items or use subscriber object to handle both item and iterate on view.

For more reference here its similar type of question link
[How to pass multiple model objects from controller and how to pass all as command objects into the form:form in spring mvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247896/how-to-pass-multiple-model-objects-from-controller-and-how-to-pass-all-as-comman)

Hope this helps